# Creating a folder when a new person registers on a form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a folder with the name as the persons username when they register on a php form but it creates a folder called $username.

The form im using the now is just a small version of the form i will be using to try and get it working.

Hope someone can help me?

```
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        enter name<input type="text" name="user">
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        include("connect.php");

        $username  = $_POST['user'];

        //Get current working directory
        $curdir = getcwd();

        include("create_folder.php");
        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>

<!--create folder.php-->
<?php
    //Name directory after username
    $uploads_dir = '/$username';

    //make directory writable from everyone
        if(mkdir($curdir . $uploads_dir , 0777)){
            echo "$uploads_dir was made";
            echo "<br>";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to create directory";
        }
?>
```

Comment: $uploads_dir = "/$username";

Comment: try tis  $uploads_dir = '/'.$username;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables do not get parsed inside single quotes.

```
$uploads_dir = '/$username';
```

I needs to read as:

```
$uploads_dir = "/$username";
```

However, if it gives you trouble, you may need to add the full system path:

I.e.:

```
$uploads_dir = "/var/users/public_html/members/$username";
```

Sidenote: `/var/users/public_html/members` is only an example. You will need to fill the actuals.

Another sidenote: Using `0777` is not recommended and is best to use `0755`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Quick draw McGraw! *Mornin' Ralph!*

Comment: *Pah-ping!* - Mornin' Sam! - @JayBlanchard

Comment: When we retire can we watch all of these old cartoons @Fred -ii-?

Comment: Thank you everyone - i got it working with your help.

Comment: *Aye,* that we will *Sam*, that we will - @JayBlanchard

Comment: @DerekKennedy If you don't tick the checkmark in the answer given, people will think the question didn't get resolved and will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will never understand these English jokes :) They are a mystery for me. (And now you would say something like: *Ralph* right ?)

Comment: @Rizier123 *RIght* ;-)

Comment: Ha! Just saw this *Ralph!* Welcome to the fun @Rizier123 - now all you need is a nickname. What say you Fred -ii-? LOL

Comment: @JayBlanchard Road Runner sounds about right to me, *beep beep!*

Comment: Oooooooo, I like that @Fred-ii- although I came close to recommending *Foghorn* ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think I'll take the *Road Runner* ;) Sounds nice and the short term would be *RR*

Comment: Alright *RR*! Are you familiar with where all of this originates @Rizier123?

Comment: @JayBlanchard not really, but it always makes me laugh, so I though I join here

Comment: Very well *RR* [Beep, beep!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8H41zbqrwVo) ;-) @Rizier123